# Print top 3 and bottom 3 scores in order from file

Tags: python, file

```
numberofbands = int(input("How many bands are there in the competition? "))



print("Input each band’s name pressing enter after each one") 

file = open("scores.txt","w") 
for loop in range(numberofbands): 
  name = input("\nEnter the name of the band: ") 
  votes = input("Enter how many votes that band received: ")
  file.write(name + "," + votes + "," + "\n") 
file.close() 

number_of_lines = len(open("scores.txt").readlines(  ))

def topbottom3():

  file = open("scores.txt", "r")
  maxScore = 0 
  maxName = "" 
  for line in file: 

    data = line.split(",") 
    highScore = data[1]
    if int(highScore) > int(maxScore): 
      maxScore = highScore 
      maxName = data[0] 
  file.close() 

  #for i in range(3):
  print("Top 3 is", maxName, maxScore)
  maxScore = int(maxScore)

  #for i in range(3):
  #   print("Bottom 3 is", minName, minScore)
  #   minScore = int(minScore)
topbottom3()
```

The user inputs a band name and score multiple times. This gets stored in a file.
I want the code to output the top 3 bands and bottom 3 bands in order.
The hashtag parts are just an idea as minScore, ect. has not been defined.

This code only outputs the highest score. I want the top 3 and bottom 3 in order to be printed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What solutions have you considered?

Comment: @PēterisCaune I thinking to run it 3 times with MaxScore - 1 each time, but in practice it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to simply use a list to store more than one value (since you are only printing one value). The code will look as follows (I formatted the variable names as Python advocates, snake case):

```
...
max_score = []
...

if int(high_score) > max(max_score): 
    max_score += [int(high_score)]
```

Remove the last line where you cast `max_score` to an `int`, and it should work.

I am curious, were you asked to write a function to find the max without using the max function? If so, we can find an alternative.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to call the function, I want to print 3 values (top 3) twice (and bottom 3). The band name followed by the score.